# CoffeeScript and NodeJS: How do I export multiple classes?

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, commonjs

I want to export some classes, say, `Dog` and `Cat`. One way to go about this is:

```
class Dog
  bark: -> console.log "Arff! :D"

class Cat
  meaow: -> console.log "Meaw!"


module.exports = {Dog, Cat}
```

How can I do something similar without typing the class names twice?

Comment: And if you add a third class, do you want to export it too?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use something like this:

```
class exports.Dog
  bark: -> console.log "Arff! :D"
```

This compiles down to:

```
exports.Dog = (function() {

  function Dog() {}

  Dog.prototype.bark = function() {
    return console.log("Arff! :D");
  };

  return Dog;

})();
```

Answer (score 3):

An alternative way to this is by doing the following:

```
module.exports = 
   Dog: class Dog
          bark: -> console.log "Arff! :D"

   Cat: class Cat
         meaow: -> console.log "Meaw!"
```

Then you can do the following:

```
animals = require './animals'

dog = new Animals.dog()
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally I want a local variable (so I don't have to type `exports.x` all the time) and an export variable (so I don't have to define all the exports at once in the end), so I do the following:

```
exports.dog = class Dog
  bark: ->

exports.cat = class Cat
  meow: ->
```